Why does the connection to redis timeout occur when fastapi and aioredis are deployed together in a docker container?
On my server, redis is deployed in containerized form.
When I access paths such as /banner, /rand, a redis connection will be corresponding, and the next step will be performed according to this connection.
When I execute the code on the server with the "python3 app.py" command, everything is normal. Similarly, when I run it on the host with the "uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000" command, there is no problem.
When I package the code and deploy it as a docker container, when executing the sentence "db_size = await redis.dbsize()", the connection timeout occurs. However, the same code can be run directly on the server through python3 or univcorn commands.
here is my source code
↓↓↓
import random
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
import aioredis

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/{path}")
async def root(path: str):
    if path == 'banner':
        storage_id = 0
    elif path == 'rand':
        storage_id = 1
    else:
        return {"code":502, 'msg':'bad request'}
    print("before aioredis.from_url")
    redis = aioredis.from_url(f"redis://**:*********@172.18.0.3/{storage_id}", decode_responses=True)
    print("before await redis.dbsize()")
    print("deadlock happened")
    db_size = await redis.dbsize()
    print("no deadlock")
    n = random.randint(0, db_size-1)
    pic_url = f"*****************"
    pic_url += await redis.get(n)
    return RedirectResponse(pic_url)
    # return {'code':Response().status_code, 'imgurl': pic_url}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

The error message is as follows：
aioredis.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout connecting to server

The service can be accessed through the external network, but a timeout occurred when executing the connection with redis.
the python version on my server is the same as the version installed by docker
I tried downgrading Python from 3.10 to 3.9, but it didn't work.
I'm wondering why the same code works fine when run directly with python3 or uvicorn, but causes a redis connection timeout when run in a docker container?
I'm connecting to Redis via ACL authentication and have configured access permissions for the container IP. So I don't think it's a firewall misconfiguration.
Finally, I was able to restore it to normal by setting the "--network host" option to the docker container, which reminded me of the same problem when I deployed cloudflare tunnel before... What is the reason?

Where does the IP address 172.18.0.3 come from?  If it's supposed to be the Docker-internal IP address of a container, you should never need to directly know or use that, and the exact IP address can change depending on the order in which networks and containers are created.  --network host is almost certainly wrong.  How are you launching the container(s)?
